# What event(s) are fired when emoji is picked in emoji keyboard?

Tags: javascript

Title says it all. Does it work the same way as regular mobile keyboard events wise?

Im unable to test it myself right now and I couldn't find anything on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `element.onkeyup` event.
It is fired when a key is entered in an input or in any `element`

Further information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeyup